# Destroying and Relaunching a PyGame object

Tags: python, pygame

I have a Python script that amongst other things opens a pygame window at one point. If this window is closed it can be reopened. If the pygame window gets opened again I get a `pygame.error: display Surface quit` in the background. Everything works perfectly fine, I can just see all the errors when I finally quit the parent script.

parent.py:

```
from game import game

def launch_game():
    game = Game() # Now I am in the pygame window until I quit it

# Do a bunch of other stuff
# At some point
launchGame()
```

game.py

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.display.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    # Set up a bunch of GPIO Controls including a quit button

        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.check_events()
            sleep(.1)
        pygame.quit()


    def check_events(self, current_station):
        if GPIO.input(self.quitButton) == 0:
            self.playing = False
        if GPIO.input(self.upButton) == 0:
            self.playing = moveUp()
        if GPIO.input(self.downButton) == 0:
            self.playing = moveDown()
```

So the first time I launchGame() happens everything works fine. The next time I start seeing the display Surface quit in the background.

One error for every time I hit one of the other buttons . The moveUp() and moveDown() functions both end with screen drawing function and that starts with `self.screen.fill(bg_color)` this is what is throwing the error.

If I open can close the game twice, I get two error message per button push, three times, three error messages. It is like the screen objects are still being kept in memory somewhere even after the `pygame.quit()` is called.

Comment: Try changing `pygame.display.init()` to `pygame.init()` and adding a `del self.screen` after `pygame.quit()`

Comment: adding `del self.screen` just changes the error to `'Game' object has no attribute 'screen'`. Changing `pygame.display.init()` to `pygame.init()` makes no difference except that it makes some other things on my raspberry pi not work smoothly because it hogs system resources.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?